# How to set an if on a select for returning select in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcommand

I have two tables named `User` and `ParentUser` that there is an one to many relation between them and the many side is the `ParentUser` table.

I have written this select on `User` table:

```
select u.* from [User] u inner join ParentUser p on u.UserId=p.UserId where p.ParentId=2440
```

Now I wanna add another column to u.* containing 0 or 1.0 is for users who have some children in `ParentUser` and 1 is for those whom dont have any.

How to handle this?

**Update**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT u.*,
       CASE
         WHEN p.ParentId IS NULL THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END AS HasChildren
FROM   [User] u
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ParentId
                  FROM   ParentUser
                  WHERE  ParentId IN (SELECT UserId
                                      FROM   ParentUser
                                      WHERE  parentId = 2440)) p
              ON u.UserId = p.ParentId
```

Comment: This is not working properly.One of my users named A has some children but itself is a child of another user named B.Your query is returning 0 for A but 1 for B.

Comment: @HamidReza - can you add sample data and expected result

Comment: Correct but how to pass a ParentId to get a specific user's children?

Comment: @HamidReza - pass the `ParentId` in where clause. updated

Comment: Sorry but this where clause return the parent record.I want all its children.

Comment: @HamidReza - you want to view the children's of parent or you want to check whether a `userid` has childern's or not. Your question says something and your comments say something else

Comment: I want to get a specific parent's children and whether every child has some children or not(because every child can has some children). I sent a photo in my question.

Comment: This change returns all users again.And one thing more by this change, HasChildren column is set to 1 for all users except the user 2440.

Comment: I wrote another question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672098/how-to-write-a-query-to-check-if-a-child-has-any-children-in-a-table

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     [UserId]       =   [u].[userid]
    ,[HasChildren]  =   CAST(ISNULL([pu].[userid], 0) AS BIT)
FROM
    [User]  AS  [u]
OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT [userid] FROM [ParentUser] WHERE [parentid] = [u].[userid]
    )       AS  [pu];
```

**And, if you want to filter by parent id:**

```
 DECLARE @ParentId INT = 2;

SELECT DISTINCT
     [UserId]       =   [u].[userid]
    ,[HasChildren]  =   CAST(ISNULL([pu].[userid], 0) AS BIT)
    ,[ChildrenId]   =   [pu].[userid]
FROM
    [user]  AS  [u]
OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT [userid], [parentid] FROM [ParentUser] WHERE [parentid] = [u].[userid]
    )       AS  [pu]
WHERE
        [pu].[parentid] = @ParentId;
```

Comment: Now I read your comments. Hmm, your problem description totally differs from your comments. My answer is correct, if you wanna result, described in a question. But, by your comments... its hard to understand what do you want. As I understand, you need recursion here.

Comment: Both queries are working properly but when I use the second query it returns the parent user.I need the children of the parent in query 2.

Comment: No.The field HasChildren's value is for the parent and set to 1 always.I write another question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672098/how-to-write-a-query-to-check-if-a-child-has-any-children-in-a-table

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to determine each user that has children. The following starts out by determining the number of children, but in final output (with other columns from user) simply reduces this to: "Are there any children?"

```
/************************* Set up sample data *************************/
declare @User table (
    UserId int,
    UserName varchar(10)
)
insert @User
select 1, 'A' union all
select 2, 'B' union all
select 3, 'C'

declare @ParentUser table (
    UserId int,
    ParentId int
)
insert @ParentUser
select 3, 1 union all
select 3, 2 union all
select 2, 1


/****************************** Solution ******************************/
;with ChildCounts as (
    select  p.ParentId, COUNT(*) as ChildCount
    from    @ParentUser p
    group by p.ParentId
), UsersWithHasChildren as (
    select  u.*,
            case
                when p.ChildCount > 0 then 1
                else 0
            end as HasChildren
    from    @User u
            left join ChildCounts p on
                p.ParentId = u.UserId
)
select  *
from    UsersWithHasChildren u
```

From your duplicate question, the special case of determining which children of a particular parent also have children is a trivial `WHERE` filter as below.

```
where   u.UserId in (
            select  p.UserId
            from    @ParentUser p
            where   p.ParentId = 1 /*Parametrise this value*/
        )
```