# How to write a query to check if a child has any children in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlcommand

I have two tables named `User` and `ParentUser` that there is an one to many relation between them and the many side is the `ParentUser` table.

I wanna write a query to pass a parentId and fetch all of its children and a column name `HasChildren` to see whether every child has any children or not.

The picture below shows some sample data and needed result:

[image]

Tries:

1-By [Prdp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3349551/prdp)

```
SELECT u.*,
       CASE
         WHEN p.ParentId IS NULL THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END as HasChildren
FROM   [User] u
       LEFT JOIN (select distinct ParentId from ParentUser) p
              ON u.UserId = p.ParentId
```

All good here but I cant pass a parentId to it.

2- By [Juozas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5967536/juozas)

```
DECLARE @ParentId INT = 2441;

SELECT DISTINCT
     [UserId]       =   [u].[userid]
    ,[HasChildren]  =   CAST(ISNULL([pu].[userid], 0) AS BIT)
    ,[ChildrenId]   =   [pu].[userid]
FROM
    [user]  AS  [u]
OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT [userid], [parentid] FROM [ParentUser] WHERE [parentid] = [u].[userid]
    )       AS  [pu]
WHERE
        [pu].[parentid] = @ParentId;
```

All good again but the field HasChildren's value is always 1.

Comment: can u plz share the query what you hv tried so far?

Comment: Why didn't you let us know that this has been asked before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set an if on a select for returning select in sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41669968/how-to-set-an-if-on-a-select-for-returning-select-in-sql)

Comment: @CraigYoung The question mentioned in your comment is mine too but as it had some misunderstanding I decided to make another.

Comment: @HamidReza I know the other is also your question. This question only needs a trivial filter added to the results of a solution to your first question. I've added an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41693652/224704) to the that question which demonstrates this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT UserId, HasChildren = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ParentUser pu2
                                              WHERE pu2.ParentId = pu.UserId)
                             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM ParentUser pu
WHERE ParentId = @ParentId
ORDER BY UserId
```